# Mongoose Validation Subdocuments Required Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying for mongoose built in validator required to work for sub document "keys"

I have created keySchema and trying to use it as subdocument

```
keys: {
 required: true,
 type: [keySchema]
}
```

I am hitting request via postman

```js
{
  "name": "dasas"
}
```

But instead of throwing error the entry is getting created inside collection

Below is my model file

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const constant = require('./base.constants');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const keySchema = Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    maxLength: 100,
    required: [true, constant.KEY_NAME_REQUIRED_ERROR],
    validate: {
      validator: function (str) {
        return constant.NO_SPACE_REGEX.test(str);
      },
      message: constant.KEY_NAME_VALIDATION_ERROR
    }
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['input', 'dropdown']
  },
  values: {
    type: [String]
  }
});

const baseSchema = Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, constant.BASE_NAME_REQUIRED_ERROR],
    unique: true,
    maxLength: 100,
    validate: {
      validator: function (str) {
        return constant.NO_SPACE_REGEX.test(str);
      },
      message: constant.BASE_NAME_VALIDATION_ERROR
    }
  },
  keys: {
    required: true,
    type: [keySchema]
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Base', baseSchema);
```

Comment: I already have a work around but don want this work around
`
baseSchema.path('keys').validate(function (value) {
  return value.length > 0;
}, constant.KEYS_REQUIRED_ERROR); `